# Get IP address and adapter description using C#

Tags: c#, networking, ip-address

I got a problem synchronizing the "IP address and Description".

The objective is this:

Get the IP address and what is the description?

Example:

```
| Atheros Azx1234 Wireless Adapter |

|192.168.1.55                      |
```

But the outcome is not what I expected...

This is my code feel free to try...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
    IPHostEntry host;
    host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());

    foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in interfaces)
    {
        foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if ((adapter.OperationalStatus.ToString() == "Up") && // I have a problem with this condition
                (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ip.ToString(), adapter.Description.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I have tried your code and it's working,can you explain the problem in more detail?

Comment: I do not think that there's a problem with the code you've posted. I've managed to get my local IP from each network device that is operating on my system :)

Comment: the problem occur when we have a multiple internet adapter..

Comment: **See "cmd > ipconfig /all" observe the message box it will repeat the ip addres**s

Comment: **The message box must preview ONLY the adapters of your computer**

Comment: I still have no clue as to what you want to see in that messagebox.

Comment: @RoiseEscalera And you haven't stated the problem. How your problem manifests?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you do not use the associated IP addresses
for the given adapter. Instead of matching all IP addresses to every adapter
use only the IP addresses associated with the current adapter:

```
NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
foreach (var adapter in interfaces)
{
    var ipProps = adapter.GetIPProperties();

    foreach (var ip in ipProps.UnicastAddresses)
    {
        if ((adapter.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
        && (ip.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork))
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(ip.Address.ToString() + "|" + adapter.Description.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This must be the solution, that's it +1

Comment: **@Hans : I have a 2 questions for you 1st how can we prevent a Loopback address from previewing in message box? 2nd How can i accept your answer? lol **

Comment: @RoiseEscalera: You can filter the loopback address by adding the following condition to your if statement: ip.Address.Equals(IPAddress.Loopback) == false. To accept my answer please click on the hollow check (tick mark) sign below the voting arrows.